# regex for valid web url and html telephone url

Tags: javascript, html, regex

```
**https://www.test.com**

I have written regex for the above url like below
/^\{[\$\w][\$\w\.\[\]]+\}|^https{0,1}:\/\/[\w\-\.:\/\$\{\}=\?&#\~]+$/

now i am trying to add **tel:15556665872** condition to the above regex like below

/^\{[\$\w][\$\w\.\[\]]+\} |^tel{0,1}:[\d]+ |^https{0,1}:\/\/[\w\-\.:\/\$\{\}=\?&#\~]+$/
```

the above regex should validate both web url and tel url, but it's validating only web url (https://www.test.com), which is not validating (tel:23423234)

Could any one help with this?

Comment: Is your JavaScript running in a browser? and what exactly are you trying to extract?

Comment: I am not extracting any thing. i am validating <a href=""> tag in text field using javascript.

Comment: What's a "html telephone"?

Answer (score 3):

If you know that you're never going to have a "<"  character inside the href you can do this:

```
/<a\s+href=["']([^>]+)['"]/i
```

If you need an explanation just ask. I recommend using [this](https://regex101.com/) site to assist you in writing regex strings.

P.S. Only use ^ and $ if the string you're trying to match is on one line. My regex above works for examples like `<div><a href="tel:15556665872">Click to Call</a></div>` but it wouldn't if I wrapped my regex string in ^$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I have updated regex could you please check and update regex

Comment: @sekhar No worries! What's wrong with the regex I've suggested in my answer? Have you posted your regex into the site I recommended in my answer to try and understand what it's doing?

Comment: what you have suggested is correct, but i have extra cases to allow url. so i am using the above one. could you please update for the above regex?

Comment: @sekhar If you provide more examples which you'd like my regex to match please provide them. I'd rather not try to work out what cases you're trying to match from the regex you've written -- it would be better for us both if you just provide more examples. Thanks

Comment: could you please check once, i have updated my question with proper examples?

Comment: @sekhar The regex in my answer matches both examples in your updated question